# Spread load on different equal cost variables in GLPK

Tags: python, glpk

Is it possible in GLPK to spread the solution over multiple equal cost variables?

Let's suppose I have this piece of code in myprog:

```
from pymprog import *

begin()

loads = var('loads', 3)
load_cost = par('load_cost', [10, 10, 10])

sum (loads[i] for i in range(len(loads))) >= 200

for i in range(len(loads)) :
   loads[i] <= 100

minimize (sum (load_cost[i] * loads[i] for i in range(len(loads))))

solve()
end()
```

Is it possible to ask the solver to return 66, 66, 66 for the three loads instead of 100, 100, 0?

Comment: Have you thought about adding a penalty term to your objective function which penalizes an unequal distribution of loads? If it is not an requirement to have a linear program, an L2 norm penality on your loads could do the job. BTW, your code results in a syntax error due to missing parentheses at line defining the minimize objective function.

Comment: thanks for correcting the typo. I'm using the pymprog library as a linear programming library. Is there a way to use it differently? Do you know other python libraries for optimization problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet solves your problem using the gekko optimization package. It results in your desired solution "66, 66, 66":

```
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np

#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO()

#initialize variables
x1,x2,x3 = [m.Var() for i in range(3)]
c1,c2,c3 = [m.Param(value=10) for i in range(3)]

#initial values
x1.value = 1
x2.value = 1
x3.value = 1


# lower bounds
x1.lower = 0
x2.lower = 0
x3.lower = 0


# upper bounds
x1.upper = 100
x2.upper = 100
x3.upper = 100


#Equations
m.Equation(x1+x2+x3>=200)

#Objective
m.Obj(x1*c1+x2*c2+x3*c3)

#Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization

#Solve simulation
m.solve()

#Results
print('')
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
print('x3: ' + str(x3.value))
```

However, if you pick different initial values, the solver might find other solutions with no equally distributed loads. To force an equal distribution over the loads you should consider modifying your objective function by adding a penality term:

```
m.Obj(x1*c1+x2*c2+x3*c3+x1*x1+x2*x2+x3*x3)
```

With this objective function the result will always be the desired one no matter what initial values you use.

Comment: Thanks BGraf. How stable is GEKKO? Are there any report about its performance wrt other optimization libraries?

Comment: I have not much experience using gekko. It is just the simplest library which supports quadratic objectives. pymprog is just for linear objectives as far as I know. Thus, it doesnt support the additional penaltiy term.